# iOS/Swift: SecItemCopyMatching yields errSecParam (-50) status for access control of biometryCurrentSet

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am currently trying to enable users of my app to add and retrieve data from the keychain using biometric authentication. When adding an item to the keychain, the call to `SecItemAdd` returns successful status, but when retrieving an item from the keychain via `SecItemCopyMatching` I get the -50 OSStatus (errSecParam), which indicates that one of my parameters are wrong.

When debugging, I removed either the `kSecAttrAccessControl` or `kSecAttrAccessible` parameters from the query, which got rid of the error. However, now I am faced with a different issue the system is retrieving the value from the keychain without first prompting the user.

**Code that either results in an errSecParam (-50) result or no authentication prompt:**

```swift
let query: [String: Any] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrService as String: "MyApp",
    kSecAttrAccount as String: "BiometricLogin",
    // removing this key from the SecItemCopyMatching query gets rid of the error but results in no authentication prompt
    kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
    kSecReturnAttributes as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
    // removing this key from the SecItemCopyMatching query gets rid of the error but results in no authentication prompt
    kSecAttrAccessControl as String: SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly, .biometryCurrentSet, nil)!,
    kSecUseAuthenticationUI as String: kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow,
    kSecUseOperationPrompt as String: "Authenticate with Biometrics"
]

let addQuery = query.merging([(kSecValueData as String, "Hi".data(encoding: .utf8)!)], uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
print(status) // prints 0, success

let retrieveQuery = query
var queryResult: AnyObject?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(retrieveQuery as CFDictionary, &queryResult)
print(status) // prints -50 if both kSecAttrAccessible and kSecAttrAccessControl are in the query, and prints 0 if either of those attributes are removed but the result is no authentication prompt
```

So my question is: How can I get the user to be prompted with an authentication prompt to retrieve data from the keychain? To reiterate, I am using `kSecClassGenericPassword`, `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly` and `.biometryCurrentSet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
```

The above key causing the issue. This needs to be removed since its already added as part of

```
SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly, .biometryCurrentSet, nil)!
```